# How to stop trading view from saving anything in cookies/local storage?

Tags: javascript, json, tradingview-api

This is my current code:

```
let defaultProps = {
            fullscreen: true,
            symbol: 'BTC',
            interval: constantValues.timeFrameToInterval(timeframe),
            container: "tv_coin_chart",
            library_path: "/charting_library/",
            locale: "en",
        };
        const widgetOptions = {
            symbol: symbol || defaultProps.symbol,
            // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
            datafeed: new window.Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(
                constantValues.CHART_DATA_FEED
            ),
            interval: defaultProps.interval,
            container: "tv_coin_chart",
            library_path: '/charting_library/',
            locale: 'en',
            disabled_features: [
                'use_localstorage_for_settings',
                'save_chart_properties_to_local_storage',
                'google_analytics',
                'header_screenshot',
                'header_saveload',
                'timeframes_toolbar',
                'items_favoriting',
                'localstorage',
            ],
            chart_storage_url: 'http://saveload.tradingview.com',
            charts_storage_api_version: '1.0',
            load_last_chart: false,
            client_id: 'xxx.trade',
            user_id: 'userId',
            settings_adapter: {
                initialSettings: {},
                setValue: function (key, value) {
                    //
                },
                removeValue: function (key) {

                },
            },
            save_load_adapter: {

            },
            autosize: true,
            theme: themeQuery || theme.palette.mode
        };

        const tvWidget = new window.TradingView.widget(widgetOptions);
        window.tvWidget = tvWidget;
```

So far everything is gone but there are 3 things that still get saved in my local storage

```
tv.logger.loglevel
tvlocalstorage.available
tv.logger.logHighRate
```

[Local Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OKps.jpg)

Using these properties I got rid of most of the things which got saved in cookies/local storage

```
disabled_features: [
                'use_localstorage_for_settings',
                'save_chart_properties_to_local_storage',
                'google_analytics',
                'header_screenshot',
                'header_saveload',
                'timeframes_toolbar',
                'items_favoriting',
                'localstorage',
            ],
settings_adapter: {
                initialSettings: {},
                setValue: function (key, value) {
                    //
                },
                removeValue: function (key) {

                },
            },
```

but still couldn't get rid of those 3... are there any other properties I'm missing here or is it possible in anyway even a hack fix to stop this from happening?